# Default fallback overload of a function template

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

**Short general question:**

Is there a way to provide a default "fallback" overload of a function template? I read about some techniques here on Stack Overflow, but one requires using a variadic function (`f(...)`) which has some serious drawbacks in my case, and other requires listing all the type combinations that are overloaded, which is too verbose and not automated enough for my needs. This question was asked, but it's a few years old now, so I was wondering if there are some new solutions to this using the features of the latest standards and maybe even some solutions that will be possible in C++20 using concepts.

**Long detailed question:**

I'm trying to implement something like dynamic typing in C++. The point is, that I have several "abstract" types like `Bool`, `Integer`, `Decimal`, `String` etc. that are represented with some built-in types i.e. `Integer` is stored as a `long long`, but any integral type except `bool` is converted to it.

Now I started to implement operators. I could implement every possible overload (i.e. `Bool + Integer`, `Integer + Integer`, ...) manually, but I'd like to have only one implementation per some "category" i.e. `Decimal + any_lower_type_than<Decimal> (commutative)`, where `any_lower_type_than<Integer>` refers to certain hierarchy of the abstract types. I have all the needed metafunctions to distinguish the categories and hierarchy implemented. I then use SFINAE with those metafunctions to provide the definitions. For example:

```
// decimal + lower, commutative:
template <typename first_t, typename second_t,
    std::enable_if_t<commutative_with_lower<first_t, second_t, Decimal>::value>* = nullptr>
Decimal operator+ (const first_t& first, const second_t& second) {
    return first + second;
}

// string * lower than integer, commutative:
template <typename first_t, typename second_t,
    std::enable_if_t<commutative_with_lower_than<first_t, second_t, String, Integer>::value>* = nullptr>
String operator* (const first_t& first, const second_t& second) {
    String string_arg = is_string<first_t>::value ? first : second;
    auto other_arg = is_string<first_t>::value ? second : first;
    String result = "";
    for (decltype(other_arg) i = 0; i < other_arg; ++i)
        result += string_arg;
    return result;
}
```

So that's all OK, but what I need now is some default "fallback" implementation, that gets called as a last resort, when no match was found. So I need to somehow force the fallback implementation to be the worst possible match, but at the same time be a match for any case.

I read about the variadic function "sinkhole" being a worse match than anything. So the natural approach would be to provide the fallback as `operator+ (...)`, which is impossible of course. So I changed all the operators to regular functions e.g. `operator_add` and then implemented the `operator+` itself at a higher level by calling the appropriate `operator_add` overload, where the default overload is implemented as a variadic function `operator_add(...)`. But then I encountered another problem. Variadic functions accept only trivial types. But I need to use this technique for user-defined types as well.

So the question is: Is there any alternative technique to the variadic function sinkhole that would ensure the worst possible match? Is there maybe even a way to do this without modifying the functional arguments, maybe by modifying the template arguments, so that I could use the technique on actual operators, that have fixed functional arguments signature?

Comment: I think you want to create overloads with incoming **Concept**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply define your fallback to have a trailing parameter pack:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename... T>
whatever_t operator_add(A&& a, B&& b, T...)
{
    …
}
```

Overloading will always prefer non-templates over templates and prefer a more specialized template to a less specialized template. Based on [[temp.deduct.partial]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.partial#11), if two function templates are otherwise equally well-suited the one with a trailing parameter pack loses.

The only downside of this approach is that there will be potential issues should you ever plan to add overloads of `operator_add()` that take more than two arguments. Also, should someone accidentally pass more than two arguments, the fallback would be called and just swallow them. Unfortunately, due to the issue mentioned in the comments by Jarod42, we cannot simply use `std::enable_if` to remove the overload in case there actually happen to be arguments for the parameter pack (like I originally proposed). One thing you could do to at least guard against the accidental call is just add another overload that would be called in this case and define it as deleted:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C, typename... T>
void operator_add(A&&, B&&, C&&, T...) = delete;
```

Comment: That seems like the trick I needed. Other answers look interesting too, so depends on the current situation, but this one seems to be the simplest one for my situation.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is ill-formed NDR [temp.res#8.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.res#8.3).

Comment: @Jarod42 I was not aware of that rule, thanks for pointing that out. While that's unfortunate, the `enable_if` is not really all that necessary anyways, you could simply remove it. It was merely meant as protection for the case that you'd one day have a version of `operator_add` that takes more than two arguments or you'd accidentally call it with more than two arguments. As long as you don't it should still work just fine without the `enable_if`…

Comment: @McSim I updated my answer to account for what Jarod42 pointed out.

Comment: @Jarod42 out of curiosity, do you know what exactly the rationale is behind this rule? I'm not sure: what counts as a "valid specialization"? Would it be valid to use a `static_assert(sizeof...(T) > 0)` inside the template definition instead (which would then make the program ill-formed if the template would ever be instantiated with a non-empty parameter pack)?

Comment: Just asked [why-template-with-only-valid-empty-variadic-pack-ill-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545650/why-template-with-only-valid-empty-variadic-pack-ill-formed) about the rationale.

Answer (score 2):

Add another parameter to your `operator_add`s, including the fallback.

Give the fallback's extra parameter a different type (say, `long`), than the rest (say, `int`).

Make your `operator+` call it with an `int` argument so that the fallback has a worse conversion.

Comment: Thanks. That looks quite straightforward, but requires more changes in all the overloads. I'll test that.

Answer (score 2):

> So the question is: Is there any alternative technique to the variadic function sinkhole that would ensure the worst possible match?

You might use hierarchy to order overloads:

```
template <std::size_t N> struct overloadPriority : overloadPriority<N -1> {};
template <> struct overloadPriority<0>{};
```

then

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<MyTrait5<T>::value> foo_impl(T&&, overloadPriority<5>) {/*..*/}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<MyTrait4<T>::value> foo_impl(T&&, overloadPriority<4>) {/*..*/}

// ...

template <typename T>
void foo_impl(T&&, overloadPriority<0>) {/*..*/} // Fallback


template <typename T>
auto foo(T&& t)
{
    return foo_impl(std::forward<T>(t), overloadPriority<42>{});
    // number greater or equal to max overload_priority used by that overload.
}
```

Comment: I like that solution. It adds a lot of explicit control over the overload resolution. But it adds a lot of changes to the code, so I chose the other one as the correct answer as it's a simple drop-in  solution to give the lowest priority to a single overload.