# Why template with only valid empty variadic pack ill formed?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

What is the rationale of

[temp.res#8.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.res#8.3)

> (8) The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation. [ Note: Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template to be checked in this way. — end note ] The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>   [..]
>   (8.3) every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack, or

That rule disallows trick as following to force template deduction as:

```
template <typename ...Ts,
          typename A,
          typename B,
          std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Ts) == 0, int> = 0> // Ill-formed NDR :-(
Pair<std::decay_t<A>, std::decay_t<B>> MakePair(A&&a, B&& b)
{
    return {a, b};
}
```

Note: I know that C++17 deduction rule makes `make_*` obsolete.

Comment: Is this ill formed?  The quote says specialization, which you don't have.  Wouldn't wording need to instantiation instead to make it ill formed?

Comment: @NathanOliver is not an specialization but every specialization from it will require an empty pack.

Comment: @NathanOliver Specialization is the term in the standard (that nobody uses) which means a specific template instantiation.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Thanks.  That will clear up some misunderstandings I've had with [temp.res]/8 lately.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, [temp.res]/8 is certainly in the spotlight recently. Came up at least 3 times in the last 4 days, including my question. I would like to know rationale myself, if there is any other than just to "give compilers more liberty".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, implementations can diagnose obvious errors in templates early, since you can't generate a valid instantiation anyway. But pack expansion is a bit unique because the whole construct can just disappear when instantiated. The rule therefore is needed to disallow various species of obvious bogosity in things being pack-expanded and permit their early diagnosis:

```
template<class...Ts>
union U : Ts... {}; // unions can't have base classes

template<class...Ts>
class C : Ts..., Ts... {}; // classes can't have duplicate direct base classes

template<class...Ts>
void f() {
    // sizeof(void) is invalid, but it can vanish
    int x[] = {(sizeof(void) + sizeof(Ts))..., 0};
}
```

This also somewhat helps compiler implementers, because their internal representation for templates need not support such nonsense.